# How to pass the variable in attachment array path?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

How do I pass the variable in attachment path you can see at the end of code I am trying to passing `'.$img_post.'` and if write the 145566.png it's work but bellow code is not working for me.

```
  $attachments = array(  '/home2/rahulr/public_html/cutting- edge/wordpress_theme/user_templates/'.$img_post.'' );
```

Comment: I should have tagged this as php as well. Is `$img_post` display `145566.png` when you print it ? Also, I suggest you to use double quotes ("") instead of single quotes ('').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, following should work (provided `$img_post` actually contains the desired value):

```
$attachments = array( '/path/to/' . $img_post );
```